# mongoose findOneAndUpdate callback with array of ids

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using findOneAndUpdate in a forEach loop to create/update multiple entries.

I would like it to return an array of all the object id's it has created or updated.

During the loop, I can see it adding data to the array, but one it leaves the loop, the array is empty.

Should the array not be populated?

here is my code.

```
var softwareArray = ["Software1","Software2","Software3"],
updatedArray = [];

softwareArray.forEach(function(software){
    Software.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            Name: software
        },
        {
            Name: software
        },
        {upsert:true},
        function(err, rows){
            updatedArray.push(rows._id);
            console.log(updatedArray); //This has data in it....
        }
    );
});
console.log(updatedArray); //This has no data in it...
```

Edit: Updated with my working changes for Thiago

```
var softwareArray = ["Software1","Software2","Software3"],
updatedArray = [];

loopSoftware(softwareArray, function(updatedArray){
    console.log(updatedArray);
    //carry on....
}

function loopSoftware(input, cb){
    var returnData = [];

    var runLoop = function(software, done) {
        Software.findOneAndUpdate(
            {Name: software},
            {Name: software},
            {upsert:true},function(err, rows){
                returnData.push(rows._id);
                done()
            }
        );
    };

    var doneLoop = function(err) {

        cb(returnData);

    };

    async.forEachSeries(input, runLoop, doneLoop);
}
```

Comment: Before you start, make sure you understood and are comfortable with the async flow in node.js. If you are, your could easily answer this question on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this will happen - just like any other networking on Node, it's asynchronous!

This means that the callback you specified for your `findOneAndUpdate` operation have not run yet when it reaches the `console.log(updatedArray);` code.

Take a look at [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) for working around this common problem.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that my loop would be blocking the code (a similar snippet, without mongoose, worked so I jumped the the conclusion it was something I had done wrong with mongoose)

I've rewritten that with [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and it works fine now. Thank you

Comment: @greensmith how did you rewrite it with async? I've tried to populate an array of "findOneAndUpdate" queries but it don't return a function as .save does.

Comment: @Thiago Miranda de Oliveira I have added my revised/working code to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I decorated your code to make you see when what is happening:

```
var softwareArray = ["Software1","Software2","Software3"],
updatedArray = [];

//  TIMESTAMP: 0

softwareArray.forEach(function(software){

    //  TIMESTAMP: 1, 2, 3

    Software.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            Name: software
        },
        {
            Name: software
        },
        {upsert:true},
        function(err, rows){
            // TIMESTAMP: 5, 6, 7
            updatedArray.push(rows._id);
            console.log(updatedArray); // This has data in it....

            // want to use the result?
            if (updatedArray.length == softwareArray.length) {
                console.log(updatedArray);
            }
        }
    );
});

// TIMESTAMP: 4

console.log(updatedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that my loop would be blocking the code (a similar snippet, without mongoose, worked so I jumped the the conclusion it was something I had done wrong with mongoose)

I've rewritten that with [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and it works fine now. Thank you